# How write to file using rapache?

Tags: r, rapache

We are trying some tables data to a file with no success.

using `write.csv`.

Here is some example code that we try:

```
> <%
> 
> X<-c(1:666)
> 
> print(X)
> 
> write.csv(X,"hh")
> 
> %>
```

Here are the rapache errors, that we can't figure:

```
RApache Warning/Error!!!

Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection
RApache Warning/Error!!!

In addition:
RApache Warning/Error!!!

Warning messages:
RApache Warning/Error!!!

1: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/step1_5.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

2: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/step1_5.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

3: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/step1_5.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

4: In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on '/var/www/brew/sampleplan/writefile.php'
RApache Warning/Error!!!

5: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open file 'hh': Permission denied
RApache Warning/Error!!!
```

Function brew returned an object of `'try-error'`. Returning HTTP response code 500.

If  some one can write us a simple example or correct our code it will be awesome.

Thank's,

Yoni & Tsvi.

Comment: R can't write to the current working directory where R was running. Sort out your permissions and try again.

Comment: And please don't cross-post! You already asked the same question on RApache mailing list!

Comment: Does your source have all the greater-than signs that I see in your question? That would probably screw it up badly. It looks like the whole script is broken, not the write.csv only.

Answer (score 4):

To make your life easier, get your code working on its own first, then introduce rApache.

The error that you are seeing means that `write.csv` cannot write to the location that you specified.  Since writing to file is a common source of problems, you should add some checking and error handling code to make things more robust.  For example,

1. Specify an absolute path (`path.expand`) or at least make sure you know where the current working directory is (`getwd`).
2. Check that the directory you are writing to exists (`file.exists`) and that you can write to it (`file.access`, with `mode = 2`).
3. Wrap your call to `write.csv` in a call to `try` or `tryCatch`.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the replies.
First, the r code works perfect with r ENV.
Second there are no permission problems. The entire computer is open to every one for r and w permission. We did that in the to avid any problems of permission. 
The getwd() command didnt repliy using the rapache 
So we really dont know what cause the problems  )-: